# How can add multiple records to postresql using a single http post

Tags: sql, postgresql

> Im working on an angular project, and just created a static tasks tab using angular cdk's drag and drop module, i have two lists, one for pending tasks, and one for completed tasks.

My tasks table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tasks
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "isComplete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT 'No Description'::text,
    CONSTRAINT tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The way im trying to do this is by a button that takes the drag & drop component data (json format), then a handler that deletes all records in that table, and then sends it through a post request to the rest api.

The question is : How do i go about making an sql request that takes json input and posts it to the table in seperate records?

Answer (score 0):

Check json_to_record(json) function:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html